# Translucent status bar configuration in webclip payload in mobileconfig file

Tags: ios, ipad, configuration, mobile-safari

When I develop web app, I can set 
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>`,
so when user will create web clip with safari browser on ipad, this page will be opened in full screen mode.

Also I can set status bar to be translucent by using next meta tag.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
```

Also I am able to configure webclip with .mobileconfig file. [Web Clip Payload](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But here I can not found option of payload to set status bar translucent.
In documentation I have found only URL, Label, Icon, IsRemovable keys. But in one example I also found FullScreen key wich set page to full screen mode but with black status bar.

Question:
May be somebody knows if it is possible to set status bar translucent in web clip payload in mobileconfig file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can't do it with mobileconfig.

I solved it in following way:

First set the meta name apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style and apple-mobile-web-app-capable in your html head section on your website.

After this you have to delete your profile with the webclip on your iOS device and reinstall it. This will clean the cache on your iOS device an reread the meta name tags from your html file.

Best regards
Filellinas